# Transform joined table to datastream

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-sql

I have a datastream which I need to join with a static table using JDBC, and then move back to datastream. The problem is I get

> Table sink '*anonymous_datastream_sink$1*' doesn't support consuming
> update and delete changes which is produced by node Join

Is there a way handle the join like an append-only stream instead of dynamic table? I know I can transform the table to changelog, but it makes the code really cumbersome to write for such relatively easy task.

```java
public class Main {

    public static class myPojo {
        public String id;

        public myPojo() {
            // Empty ctor
        }

        public myPojo(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    public static class myPojoExtra extends myPojo {
        public String extra_data;

        public myPojoExtra() {
            // Empty ctor
        }
    }

    public static void createStaticTable(StreamTableEnvironment tEnv) {
        // Define a table schema
        Schema schema = Schema.newBuilder()
                .column("id", DataTypes.STRING())
                .column("extra_data", DataTypes.STRING())
                .build();

        // Create a table
        tEnv.createTable("StaticTable", 
                TableDescriptor.forConnector("filesystem")
                .schema(schema)
                .option("path", "file:///tmp/flink")
                .format("json")
                .build());

        // Insert data
        tEnv.executeSql("INSERT INTO StaticTable VALUES ('a', 'xxxx'), ('b', 'yyyy')");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env =  StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.STREAMING);
        final StreamTableEnvironment tEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);

        // Start with datastream
        DataStream<myPojo> source = env.fromElements(new myPojo("a"), new myPojo("b"));
        tEnv.createTemporaryView("tempView", source);
        // Simulate JDBC table with filesystem table
        createStaticTable(tEnv);
        
        // Join with static table
        Table result = tEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM tempView LEFT JOIN StaticTable USING (id)");
        // Move back to datastream
        DataStream<myPojoExtra> ds = tEnv.toDataStream(result, myPojoExtra.class);
        ds.print();
        env.execute("");
    }
```

EDIT:
my latest try

```
// Define a watermark strategy
WatermarkStrategy<myPojo> watermarkStrategy = WatermarkStrategy
        .<myPojo>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
        .withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> System.currentTimeMillis());
DataStream<myPojo> source = env.fromElements(
    new myPojo("a"), 
    new myPojo("b" )
).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(watermarkStrategy);

createStaticTable(tEnv);

Schema sourceToTableSchema = Schema.newBuilder()
    .columnByMetadata("rowtime", "TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3)")
    .columnByExpression("proc_time", "PROCTIME()")
    .watermark("rowtime", "SOURCE_WATERMARK()")
    .build();
tEnv.createTemporaryView("tempView", source, sourceToTableSchema);

// Join with static table
Table result = tEnv.sqlQuery(
    "SELECT id, extra_data FROM tempView LEFT JOIN StaticTable FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF tempView.proc_time USING (id)"
);
DataStream<myPojoExtra> ds = tEnv.toDataStream(result, myPojoExtra.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

For a streaming join to be semantically correct, an update stream (either retracting or upserting) is the only possible outcome. What you could consider is to replace your streaming join with a temporal join. That would give you an append-only stream as output.

Comment: I tried (added update below) and I'm getting `org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Processing-time temporal join is not supported yet.`

Comment: Processing-time temporal joins are not supported, so you'll need to use `FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF tempView.rowtime`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks! really loved your course! any idea why in the documentation they are doing processing-time temporal joins like they are supported? (in the lookup join section) https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#lookup-join

Comment: using rowtime raises `Event-Time Temporal Table Join requires both primary key and row time attribute in versioned table, but no row time attribute can be found.` but the lookup table I'm trying to join with doesn't have row time

Comment: There are two types of temporal joins in Flink. The other variety that does a lateral join with a temporal table function is only supported from the table api, and can do a processing time temporal join.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your table to toRetractStream(). As retract stream have record with row indetifying delete/insert using boolean true(insert)/false(delete), you can filter the delete row something like this -

```java
DataStream<Tuple2<Boolean, myPojoExtra>> retractDs = tEnv.toRetractStream(result, myPojoExtra.class);

//filter row with boolean value false(meaning delete)
DataStream<Tuple2<Boolean, myPojoExtra>> InsertOnlyStream =  retractDs.filter(x->x.f0)
```

Refer Retract Stream https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/dev/table/concepts/dynamic_tables/#table-to-stream-conversion